# Change scientific notation into integer in IMPALA

Tags: sql, cloudera

How can I chance `custno`: 5.0256926E7 into a normal integer / number in Impala SQL?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT * FROM z9_strategy.dstool_model_data_m 
WHERE snapshot_date_key = 20170630 
  AND custtype_ind = 1 
  AND retailer_retail = 1 
  AND CAST((custno AS FLOAT) AS int);
```

I also tried `SELECT CAST(CAST(custno AS FLOAT) AS int)`

Comment: Have you tried `cast()`?

Comment: i TRIED:SELECT *
  FROM z9_strategy.dstool_model_data_m
        WHERE snapshot_date_key = 20170630 AND custtype_ind = 1 AND retailer_retail = 1
        and CAST((custno  AS FLOAT) AS int);  BUT DOES NOT WORK

Comment: I also tried select CAST(CAST(custno  AS FLOAT) AS int)

Comment: . . Those conversions would work in most databases.

Answer (score 1):

Use [CAST](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_cast.asp):

```
CAST(custno AS int);
```